# 'Null pointer access' when using java output parameters

Tags: java, eclipse, parameters

I am working in java and wanting to use something like output parameters. Here is an example:

```
ClassA objA = null;  
if(myMethod(objA))  
{  
   // position (1)
   //use objA somehow  
}
```

======================

```
public bool myMethod(ClassA obj)   
{   
     obj = .....   
}
```

I am using Eclipse and the problem I'm having is that eclipse shows the warning:
 `Null pointer access. The variable objA can only be null at this location` when i reach position (1)

Since there is no concept of `out` parameters in java i'm a little stumpped

==================================================================
EDIT: I have gotten several people mention to change the method to return my object instead of bool. But what If i need a method to alter several objects? 
ex:

```
 ClassA objA = null;  
  ClassB objB = null;
    if(myMethod(objA, objB))  
    {  
       // position (1)
       //use objA and objB somehow  
    }
```

======================

```
public bool myMethod(ClassA obj, ClassB obj2)   
{   
     //do stuff 
}
```

How can I do this? I dont want to make a custom class for every flavor of return objects possible?

thanks,
Stephanie

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't really do what you're trying to do in java since, as you say, java doesn't support output parameters.

Method parameters are local variables, so making assignments to them has no effect outside the scope of the method.  In other words, this:

```
public void foo(Object obj) {
    obj = new Object();
}
```

Is effectively equivalent (from the point of view of the code calling foo(Object)) as this:

```
public void foo() {
    Object obj = new Object();
}
```

Pointless, since the created object will be thrown out once `foo()` returns.

Probably, what you want to do is change your method to return the object your method creates:

```
public ClassA myMethod() {
   ClassA obj = ....
   ...
   return obj;
}
```

Then in your calling code:

```
ClassA objA = myMethod();
if (objA != null) {
    ...
}
```

Alternatively, you could instantiate the instance of ClassA outside your method and pass that value is, and have the method modify it in some way:

```
public boolean myMethod(ClassA obj) {
    obj.setValue(...);
    return true;
}

...

ClassA objA = new ClassA();
if (myMethod(objA) {
   Object val = objA.getValue();
   ...
}
```

Without knowing more about your specific problem, it's hard to say which design is better.

UPDATE:

The multi-parameter example you added is flat-out impossible in java, unfortunately.  Everyone says java is pass-by-reference, but in reality it's more like pass-by-reference-value.  A method can modify *objects* passed to it, but it cannot modify what the variables in the calling scope refer to.  If you come from a C++ background, object references in java are more like pointers (without the pointer arithmetic) than they are like C++ references.

To make this more concrete, consider the following class:

```
public class ParameterPassing {
    public static void setParams(Integer value1, Integer value2) {
        System.out.println("value1 before: " + value1);
        System.out.println("value2 before: " + value2);
        value1 = new Integer(1);
        value2 = new Integer(2);
        System.out.println("value1 after: " + value1);
        System.out.println("value2 after: " + value2);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer valNull = null;
        Integer val0 = new Integer(0);
        System.out.println("valNull before: " + valNull);
        System.out.println("val0 before: " + val0);

        setParams(valNull, val0);

        System.out.println("valNull after: " + valNull);
        System.out.println("val0 after: " + val0);
    }
}
```

When you run this, you'll get this output:

```
valNull before: null
val0 before: 0
value1 before: null
value2 before: 0
value1 after: 1
value2 after: 2
valNull after: null
val0 after: 0
```

As you can see, the assignments inside the `setParams()` method have no effect on what `valNull` and `val0` refer to.

If you really need multiple "output" parameters for a single method, you're going to have to wrap them in some other object, or rethink your design.  Perhaps you could make the references member variables rather than locals and have your method modify them directly:

```
public class MyClass {
    private ClassA objA;
    private ClassB objB;

    ...

    private boolean initObjects() {
        objA = ...;
        objB = ...;
        return true;
    }

    public void otherMethod() {
        ...
        if(initObjects() {
            // Use objA, objB
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Im confused by your last example. Is it showing that if i allocate memory for the instance of the object then when I pass it back and forth it is actually operating on the same instance? So my only problem is that I was instantiating to null before passing it to myMethod?

Comment: There IS a way to use Ref parameters, using the `java.util.concurrent.atomic` toolset to wrap objects. After all, it's perfectly possible to receive an existing object and **just change its internal properties**. A function can _edit_ an object, but if you try _replacing_ it you're only replacing your local variable by a reference to a new object. It doesn't influence the original object in any way; you just stop using it at that point.

Answer (score 5):

> Since there is no concept of out
>   parameters in java ...

The reference `obj` is a copy of the reference `objA`, so assigning a new object to `obj` will not change `objA`. This means that using `obj` as an out parameter is not supported by java.

Because of this a java method can return only one value. The following are possible solutions/workarounds.

Solution 1: exception instead of boolean (only if boolean indicates an error)

```
ClassA objA = null;  
try{
   objA = myMethod();
   //DO something with objA
}catch(MyException ex){
}
```

Solution 2: return null in case of an error.

```
ClassA objA = null;  

   objA = myMethod();
  if(objA != null)
{ //DO something with objA
}
```

Solution 3: use a Pair  to return several values

```
MyPair mp = myMethod();
if(mp.first){
}

MyPair myMethod(){
   MyPair ret = new MyPair();
   mp.first = ...;//boolean
   mp.second = new ClassA();
   return ret;
}

class MyPair {
   boolean first;
   ClassA second;
}
```

Soultion 4: use single element arrays - ugly only use in extreme cases

```
ClassA[] objA = new ClassA[1];
if(myMethod(objA))
{
}

boolean myMethod(ClassA[] obj){
   obj[0] = new ClassA();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Java is pass by value. When you assign a value to `obj` in myMethod, you assign a new value to a **copy** of the pointer of the calling code. The calling code's pointer continues pointing to its initial object, which is null. This is why Eclipse warns you : you're trying to use objA, which is null, whatever you do in myMethod.

Answer (score 1):

Assigning a value to `obj` within `myMethod` will not change the value of `objA`. In Java, references are passed by value. If you want `myMethod` to initialize an instance of `ClassA`, you should move that logic either into a constructor of `ClassA` or a factory method.

To signal an error condition, you would throw an exception instead of returning a boolean value.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that behavior is not supported in Java; i.e you can't do that.  Return your object or null instead of a bool.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you can't do that with Java. When you call a method, you are passing a reference to the object, you are not passing a memory location that a method can write to. What you can do is pass in an object and allow the function to manipulate the object. Then when the function returns, you can access the fields that were manipulated but the function.

```
ClassA objA = new ClassA();  
if(myMethod(objA))  
{  
   objA.getValue();
}

public boolean myMethod(ClassA obj)   
{   
     obj.assignValue(1);
     return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, Eclipse is right in this case. Consider the following code:

```
public class NullThing {
  private static class ClassA {
    public int x;
  }

  public static boolean myMethod(ClassA obj) {
    obj = new ClassA();
    obj.x = 5;
    return obj.x == 5;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ClassA objA = null;
    if (myMethod(objA)) {
      System.out.println(objA.x);
    }
  }

}
```

If you compile this with `javac` to avoid Eclipse's warning, you'll end up with:

```
adrian:~/ $ javac NullThing.java                                                                                                                      [14:05:47]
adrian:~/ $ java NullThing                                                                                                                            [14:06:43]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at NullThing.main(NullThing.java:15)
```

Read about Java's semantics in this area in this section of the [Java Language Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.4.1), but it's probably pretty obvious from the code snippet what's actually going on.